# Adding a div into another div adds white space in sibling div

Tags: css, reactjs

I built a simple tasks app that has two categories: sports and work.

You can add task to either category and click add, then the task get rendered inside a div that represents the appropriate category. now the issue is that if I add a task say in sports, it get rendered in the sports category div but in the works category div it adds space to match it. I know I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out.

Here is a screenshot from the app, demonstrating what I mean:

[image]

```
Styles for the parent container:
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
```

Styles for the tasks container:

```
export const TasksContainer = styled.div`
  color: #fff;
  ${oneMarginRem};
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #5486d9;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
`;
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? you don't want category get the same size as sport?

Comment: @Pedram I want the space created in each category to be relevant only to the tasks inside it, as you can see, here is one task only added to sports but a space is created in the works, I don't want this space to be created.

Comment: Check your `css`, probably the parent of these elements has `display: flex` property. Share your `css` code here

Comment: Show your style please

Comment: The parent has flex yes, is there is any way to avoid this behaviour while keeping the parent as a flex?

Comment: @Awais added the styles in the question.

Comment: Try using `inline-block` rather then `flex`

Comment: margin-bottom:auto; (similar to align-self:start) on the task container should keep it at  top without expanding to the whole row's height where it stands .. if the smallest. - default behavior : the tallest sets the row's height and every other stretches to match the tallest. height from a row to another is independant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `align-self: flex-start;` on your elements `TasksContainer`:

```
export const TasksContainer = styled.div`
  color: #fff;
  ${oneMarginRem};
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #5486d9;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  align-self: flex-start;
`;
```

Simple `html` demo:

```css
.contaienr {
  display: flex;
}

.tasks {
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="contaienr">
  <div class="tasks">
    <h3>Sport</h3>
    <div class="content">
      blah blah blah blah
      <br/> blah blah blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tasks">
    <h3>Work</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it actually didn't make any change. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: guess you meant using it on the tasks container, not the parent?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy yes